# На сайте не отображается контент

Tags: modx, php, контент

Здравствуйте!

Был работающий сайт. Установила MODx, добавила свои шаблоны, разделила на чанки, вставила параметры TV. Проверила - всё работает. Но когда вставила текст, он не появился на сайте. Что только не перепробовала. В админке он есть, а на сайте голый шаблон. Причем все остальные страницы работают нормально, они явно всё еще управляются моим хостингом. И еще, если я добавляю в новый файл htacces содержание старого, сайт работает в полной мере, но теряет полностью управление движком.

Почему так происходит и что мне сделать, чтобы перенести свой сайт на управление MODx?

Answer (score 2):

Поправлю Вас.

Наверно, нужно использовать

```
[[+content]]
```

Если нужно вставить без чанка в сам шаблон, то

```
[[*content]]
```

Comment: Да, спасибо! Сама до этого дошла. Только у меня вставлено [*content*]. Всё работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Нашла причину! В шаблоне, точнее в чанке CONTENT нужно было в нужном месте - там, где должен находиться текст, вставить параметр `[*content*]`.